# MULTIPLY EACH ROW VALUES WITH DIFFERENT VALUES

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

## Hello everyone,

Here I am trying to do the multiplication of reach row multiplied by different values.
For example..,
I have 3 columns with

> `

```
customer_id(int) , product_name(varchar) , price(int)`
          1                    LV                5
          2                    MK                15
          3                    YSL               16
```

I would like to multiply each Product_name = LV, MK by 10 and Product_name = YSL by 20.
Could you please tell me how can I achieve this..,

Your help could be appreciated

Comment: share the codes what you have tried and where you stuck in between. We can not write a full code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it done by incorporating a CASE statement directly in the SQL.

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  product_name,
  CASE
    WHEN product_name IN ('LV', 'MK') THEN price * 10
    WHEN product_name = 'YSL' THEN price * 20
    ELSE price
  END as adjusted_price
FROM TABLENAME;
```